# MFC - Change mouse cursor by clicking a button

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm creating a program that the user can draw shapes and also delete them (like Paint).
For a good user experience, I want to change the mouse cursor to "eraser" to erase shapes.
This will happen when the user clicks on the "Delete" button.
After the user finish, return it back to the old cursor, again by clicking a button.

How can I achieve such a thing like that?

For example: In this function, I want to change the cursor. It triggers when the user click on the "Delete" button

```
void CMFCApplicationDlg::OnBnClickedButtonDeleteBtn()
 {
   SetCursor() // ???
   if (!toDelete)
     toDelete = true;
   else
     toDelete = false;

 }
```

Comment: Update state in response to the button click, and call [SetCursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcursor) from the [CWnd::OnSetCursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#onsetcursor) override. Make sure the window class is registered without a default cursor assigned.

Answer (score 0):

In your CView class, you can just use the following:

```
SetCursor(theApp.LoadStandardCursor(IDC_ARROW));
```

In WinUser.h, you have the following definition for cursors:

```
/*
 * Standard Cursor IDs
 */
#define IDC_ARROW           MAKEINTRESOURCE(32512)
#define IDC_IBEAM           MAKEINTRESOURCE(32513)
#define IDC_WAIT            MAKEINTRESOURCE(32514)
#define IDC_CROSS           MAKEINTRESOURCE(32515)
#define IDC_UPARROW         MAKEINTRESOURCE(32516)
#define IDC_SIZE            MAKEINTRESOURCE(32640)  /* OBSOLETE: use IDC_SIZEALL */
#define IDC_ICON            MAKEINTRESOURCE(32641)  /* OBSOLETE: use IDC_ARROW */
#define IDC_SIZENWSE        MAKEINTRESOURCE(32642)
#define IDC_SIZENESW        MAKEINTRESOURCE(32643)
#define IDC_SIZEWE          MAKEINTRESOURCE(32644)
#define IDC_SIZENS          MAKEINTRESOURCE(32645)
#define IDC_SIZEALL         MAKEINTRESOURCE(32646)
#define IDC_NO              MAKEINTRESOURCE(32648) /*not in win3.1 */
#if(WINVER >= 0x0500)
#define IDC_HAND            MAKEINTRESOURCE(32649)
#endif /* WINVER >= 0x0500 */
#define IDC_APPSTARTING     MAKEINTRESOURCE(32650) /*not in win3.1 */
#if(WINVER >= 0x0400)
#define IDC_HELP            MAKEINTRESOURCE(32651)
#endif /* WINVER >= 0x0400 */

#if(WINVER >= 0x0606)
#define IDC_PIN            MAKEINTRESOURCE(32671)
#define IDC_PERSON         MAKEINTRESOURCE(32672)
#endif /* WINVER >= 0x0606 */
```